# Is there any way to change main window icon color on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code, themes

I have this blue color icon on windows VS code that is not really fits color themes i'm using. To clarify - I’m not asking about the icon on the taskbar, I’m asking about the upper left corner icon. Screenshot attached. Thank you in advance!

[blue icon example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahSzQ.png)

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The official answer according to VSCode's issues page : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/56857

> This goes against our branding guidelines since we only ever use Blue (Stable), Green (Insiders), Orange (Explorations), Black/White when needed.

I don't know if there is a workaround.